# how to write multiple lambda values together with Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.textboxfor

I try to display birthdate like 22.10.1984 using textboxfor in MVC but I couldnt figure out how to put that together?

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirthDay + "." + model => model.DateOfBirthYear + "." + model => model.DateOfBirthYear)
```

Comment: You can't. Just have a `DateTime` property and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.yourDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke:No unfortunately i cant change the database and model because of I am just building a plugin for my customer and requirement is without touching DB. otherwise it would be the easiest.

Comment: What has the database got to do with it. Use a view model! And since this cant possibly bind to anything if you don't use a view model, then what would be the point

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok I express maybe the wrong way. Source code is fixed. I just build a plugin around. I cant change the model. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your model as suggested in the comments, you could just do this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", model.DateOfBirthDay, model.DateOfBirthMonth, model.DateOfBirthYear))
```